# Is it possible to parse Vue.js data with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-i18n

I have a line of jQuery code:

```
$("#showNames").text("{{ $t('hide_labels') }}");
```

I'd like to set text of the `#showNames` element with the value taken from my `vue-i18n` instance, dependent on user localization. When it's written this way, I get the literal moustache syntax contents. Is there any way to get the values displayed?

Comment: just get vue data directly without messing with the dom at all

Comment: @BertEvans: worked, with one comment: it has to be "this.$t". Please publish it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$("#showNames").text(this.$t('hide_labels'));
```

if you so choose. Generally it's best to use Vue methods to update the DOM, but this is available to you if you really need it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand how Vue.js works, it is not posible to parsue vue.js templates directly from jquery. However you have some choices with this problem e.g:

- call function `$("#showNames").text(translate('hide_labels'));` where `translation` function return translation.
- use `{{ $t('hide_labels') }}` inside vue.js template (without using jquery)